# php mvc object interaction

Tags: php, oop, object

I am in somewhat a mix of MVC and objects and I was wondering if I am going about it the right way or if i could change something to improve my ways.

I have a webapp that uses an MVC model with objects. I chose to use objects as well so i can load them whereever i need them. One of the objects is a Tag object (which extends the basemodel for DB access). With my MVC framework I can load models from the basecontroller and also form the basemodel (both run their own instance). At first I was loading the Tag object from the controller. Today I decided to load it from the model. Both methods work fine, but what would be the better choice and why?

From the controller (tag_controller.php)

```
function getTags()
{
    $this->_tagobject = $this->load->object('tagobject');
    $tags = $this->tags-getSomeTags();
}
```

From the controller with model. 
tagmodel.php

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->_tagobject = $this->load->object('tagobject');
}

function getTags()
{
    return $this->_tagobject->getTags();
}
```

tagcontroller.php

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->_tagmodel = $this->load->model('tagmodel');
}

function getTags()
{
    $this->_tagmodel->getTags();
}
```

Any suggestions for improvement are very welcome, because I can't seem to see a real benefit besides having a flexible object.

Comment: could you show some of your code

Comment: You need to give more details before anyone can make a sensible suggestion.

Comment: Sure. i have added some code. i hope this explains it better.

Comment: What are the "objects" you are talking about ? In OOP terminology ant instance of a class is an object. Thus "MVC model with objects" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

For most applications, your interaction with a tag object would follow CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) so to me it leans more towards the model.

If I were to use tags in Zend Framework (MVC based PHP framework), I would create a `tags` class extending the Zend_Db_Table class and also a `tag` class representing the individual data object so I would be able to use it like:

```
$tags->insert(new Tag('keyword'));
$tags->find('keyword');
$tags->delete('keyword');
```

Placing this functionality in a controller wouldn't make sense. Then again, that's all my opinion.

Comment: And in Zend, does the tag class get loaded from the model?

Comment: I was using ZF as an example. As far as loading goes, I would autoload it (see: lazy initialization) and just use it when I need it.